# Is there a workaround for 2 min delayed response if Google Sheet was just edited?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm seeing delayed responses of several minutes if my Google Apps web app attempts to read data from a spreadsheet that was changed moments before the request.

I'd like to know if this is normal and expected or whether I am doing something wrong.

My GAS script is a standalone project, not bound to a specific sheet.

If I were to attach an `onEdit()` handler to the sheet itself, (which read from the affected area, for example), would it wake up the caching system, (or whatever there is intervening between the sheet and my script), and set it up for a more rapid response?

*Update*: I experience the delay when running the script in dev mode.  The  published script called from a web page throws an Error 500 (Internal server error.)

*Update*:  To explain the steps in more detail. In the GAS editor I have a `getSingleRow()` method, a `testGetSingleRow()` method and a `doGet()` method.  The latter two both call the former in exactly the same way:

1. If I use the GAS editor to call `testGetSingleRow()` locally, I get the data back in about 1.5 seconds.
2. If I use my web page to call `doGet()` remotely, I get the data back in about 5 seconds.
3. If I edit the single row, and then immediately use the GAS editor to call `testGetSingleRow()` locally, there is a delay of almost exactly two minutes!
4. If I edit a different row, and then immediately use my web page to call `doGet()` remotely, I get `Error 500` back after about 30 seconds.

*Update*: **I have decided that the sheet was probably corrupted internally.  Closing question.**

Comment: Do you mean that the data you read from the spreadsheet is not up to date when you read it from your web App ? I use this workflow a lot and never experienced anything like that.

Comment: Without seeing code, "Error 500" doesn't really mean much to us. If you subscribe to the file in Drive API, and use the change notification, do your queries to get updated data fail then too?

Comment: @Sergeinsas -- I have elaborated further; see update, please.  I would like to ask, in your usual workflow, are your scripts standalone, or bound to the spreadsheet?  I'm wondering if the behaviour is different between the two cases.

Comment: @tehhowch -- I understand.  There's always a trade off between keeping a question simple and supplying every possibly relevant detail.  For the moment, I'm just hoping for a true/false response about the behaviour I'm seeing:  Eg; "Google's 'eventually consistent' data distribution causes the 2 minute delay you are seeing and there is no way around it." True? False?

Comment: Post an mcve and we'll test. I find it hard to imagine how you're getting err 500.

Comment: @tehhowch - I am going to close this tomorrow.  I made a copy of the script, a copy of the sheet, stripped everything irrelevant out of the sheet, and the problem went away.  It was a big old legacy sheet  from which we are migrating away.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @martin standalone script.